# Print between patterns -awk

Tags: perl, awk, printing, sed, pattern-matching

I have the following input file

```
-------------------------------------
--- A-TKE spectrum (post-neutron)---
-------------------------------------

2-dim. array: (A =  73 To  162 Step 1) (E =  122 To  198 Step 1)

(The data are written according to the loop structure specified above.
The last loop is the inner-most one. Line breaks are not related to the data structure!

 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 2 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 


    </A_TKE>
  </Results>
```

This file is part of a bigger file, which contains more number block similar to the above one.

What I want to do is print in a seperate file the numbers that are within the file. As a first try, I thought "Let's print what is between two patters". The START pattern will be `--- A-TKE spectrum (post-neutron)---` and the END pattern will `</A_TKE>`

I used

```
awk '/--- A-TKE spectrum (post-neutron)---/{flag=1;next}/</A_TKE>/{flag=0}flag{print}' input
```

To my surprise nothing is printed on the screen. Any idea on why is this happening?

I would also like to now if I can substitue `next` with a number that will correspond to the line that I want to print after the given pattern.

Comment: Those look like `XML` tags. Are they?

Comment: @Sobrique : No :) It's just an output file of a code, that I want to manipulate!

Comment: Which numbers do you want to print? Please specify the output that you expect.

Comment: @skmrx : I'd to print the massive block of numbers

Answer (score 3):

In perl (because whilst you start with `awk`, this is tagged as `perl` too):

```
perl -ne 'print if m/post-neutron/...m/A_TKE/' input
```

Which will do what your thingy was trying to.

It works by using the [`range operator`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) - which is a perl construct which tests if the current file is between two markers.

And the fact that `perl` can run inline in the same way as `awk` or `sed`. `-ne` says "wrap this code in a while loop" that iterates a line at a time. (e.g. as `sed`/`awk`/`grep` do by default).

Otherwise ... it depends a little on what *else* is in your file. Because from the sample you gave - the only lines starting with a number are the ones you want.  So:

```
perl -ne 'print if m/^\s*\d+\s*\d+/'
```

(Or combine the two tests:

```
perl -ne 'print if m/post-neutron/...m/A_TKE/ and m/^\s*\d+\s*\d+/'
```

Which will output anything between the two text markers that has number-space-number at the start of line.

Answer (score 3):

Your awk script is almost there.  I'd build it like this:

```
awk '
  /<\/A_TKE>/ {exit}
  flag && NF==50 {print} 
  /--- A-TKE spectrum .post-neutron.---/ {flag=1}
' input
```

You could optimize it of course, but just looking at the logic of it, the idea is that you need do no further processing once you hit your end marker .. and you only want to start printing AFTER your start marker.

Note that I've replaced the brackets in your start marker with dots, since brackets are interpreted as PART OF THE REGULAR EXPRESSION. I believe you may be considering these simple strings to search for, but they are regex.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is that the file that I attached, is part of a bigger file which contains `<A-TKE>`. So the difference is just this slash, therefore I think it's necessary

Comment: I run awk ' ///A_TKE/{exit}flag{print} /--- A-TKE spectrum .post-neutron.---/{flag=1}' but I get a syntax error at `{exit}`

Comment: Ah, of course I didn't know about the earlier flag.  In your comment, your awk script starts with `///A_TKE/`.  Shouldn't that be `/\/A_TKE/`?  The backslash "escapes" the forward slash which would otherwise be interpreted as a regex delimiter. Also, what OS are you running and/or what version of Awk?

Comment: Yes you are right. I am running `Ubuntu 12.041 and my `awk` version is `3.1.8`.

Comment: @Thanos, I've improve the end-marker detection and added another condition to the second expression in the script.  With this version, only the lines with 50 fields (as delimited by whitespace) get printed. Also, for reference, you are not using `awk`, you're actually using `gawk` (GNU awk). Gawk has a number of extra features that traditional awk is missing (though nothing we need to solve your issue).

Answer (score 2):

**Some working ideas**

Awk can print between two matching lines with this simple command:

```
awk '/PATTERN1/,/PATTERN2/' file.txt
```

If you want more control over what happens when the lines are found, you can use the flag approach.

```
awk '/A-TKE/{f=1;for (i=0;i<7;i++){getline}}/A_TKE/{f=0}f' file.txt
```

Adjust `i<7` to specify how many lines you would like to skip.

Also, in this particular case, you can exploit the fact that you have 50 fields of numbers, which is unlikely to occur anywhere else in the file. Thus, you could also get the numbers of interest out with:

```
awk 'NF>40' file.txt
```

`NF` is a special awk variable that stores the number of fields (columns) in the current record (line).

**Why your approach does not work**

Your approach does not work, because everything that is between `//` in awk is treated as a regular expression. In your case you have several `-` and `()` in the string, which are not escaped, and thus assume their special meaning and therefore the expression you typed never matches, thus the flag is never set to 1 and awk does not print a line.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract rows with just numbers

```
 awk 'NF && !/[a-zA-Z\-]+/' input.file
```

will generate

```
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 2 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
```

with patterns and smart counters you can write it as

```
awk   '/\/A_TKE/{exit} 
       f&&s&&s--{next} 
           f&&NF{print} 
/A-TKE spectrum/{f=1;s=7}' input.file
```

fine tune patterns as you like.

Comment: I dindn't mention it in my initial question, but this is just a part of a bigger file that contains more number blocks, therefore I think I have to stick with patterns

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple `sed` command

```
sed -n '/A-TKE/,/<\/A_TKE>/p' FileName
```